# how to use if statement in R with 2 conditions

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

[image: click me]

and I want to find the total number of test group(exposed) when the purchased is 1

```
for (i in df$exposed) {
  if (i == "Test Group (Exposed)" && df$purchased == 1){
    
    print(i)

  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally use `sum` to count things - this is true in a lot of programming languages. TRUE is 1, FALSE is 0, so the sum of TRUE/FALSE values is the number of trues. In your case:

```
sum(df$exposed == "Test Group (Exposed)" & df$purchased == 1)
```

No `for` loop or `print` needed.

Similarly, you can use `mean()` to get the percent of TRUE values.

If you wanted to do this for groups (e.g., get the number of rows with 1 purchase for all the `exposed` categories) see the FAQ on [how to sum a variable by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061).

Comment: `grepl` may avoid some typo issues